# What's the difference between destroy the objects and free the associated memory

Tags: c++

I have been diving into C++ primer 5th edition these days. I found that on the page 452-453, it says `shared_ptr` automatically destroys its objects and frees the associated memory.
I don't quite understand it.  So what's the difference between destroy the objects and free the associated memory?

Comment: Looks like another way to say `delete` (=destroy + deallocate).

Answer (score 4):

Consider an object of this class:

```
class foo {
    double* a;
    foo() { a = new double();}
    ~foo() {delete a;}
}
```

If you want to clean up after using such an object, it is not sufficient to free the memory of that object, but you have to call the destrcutor so that also `a` gets deleted properly.

Comment: Here is my understanding. A foo object contains two kind of memory. The memory of pointer and the memory of value that pointer points. So, if I free the memory of the object, the memory of the pointer is not freed?

Comment: @LiuHao The size of a `foo` object is only the size of a pointer to double, but the double itself is stored "somewhere else"

Comment: Got it. Thx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

When you create an object dynamically you first allocate memory for it (which is just some bytes). Then you run the constructor to construct an object instance in those bytes - initialise members, acquire resources, and so on.

When you are finished with the object you have to do this in reverse. First the destructor is run, which frees up any resources owned by the object. Now you are once again left with some bytes that used to contain an object. And then you need to free the bytes and enable the system to reuse them for something else.

Comment: I got it. destructor is not equal to freeing memory.

Answer (score 2):

Destroying objects and freeing their memory are very closely related actions, analogously to acquiring memory and constructing objects in it.

Let's say you have some paper and you draw on some nice anti-terrorism expression. You then decide to draw something else: using a rubber you clear what you have drawn, but the paper is still there!

This is the same for objects and memory: objects exist in memory, therefore you have to acquire it before constructing them, and drawings are constructed on paper. When you don't need the drawing anymore, you clear the paper (destroy the object); that doesn't mean you can't make a new drawing on the old, still "acquired", paper. If you're really done with it, you destroy the object and release its memory, that is where it used to reside. This also means you'll need to acquire the memory again to "draw" again.

Answer (score 1):

Destroying an object is about releasing the resources the object eventually acquired during its lifetime and the object memory itself.

Concretely it means that the shared pointer will call a deleter function when the reference count is 0. By default, it is the `delete` method, but you can supply custom deleters too.

Comment: Thank you! Really helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an informal terminology that make distinct some operations when creating and deleting an object.

**Creation** (can be made with `new`) **allocates** memory and then initializes/**constructs** the object.

**Deletion** (can be made with `delete`) **destroys**/de-initliazes the object and then **deallocate** the associated memory.

Author certainly uses destroy to means that the destructor is called.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose "destroying" an object could be just deleting the pointer to it, while "freeing the associated memory" literally means releasing the lock on the memory. At least that's what I think the author was trying to get at, anyway.

Comment: _"lock"_ what please??